# TIdHTTP in Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal

I used to use Indy back in the Delphi 6 days, and I am playing with Indy 10 now.  What I want to do is incredibly simple, but I don't see a simple way of doing it, so I must be missing something.

What I want to do is something like this:

Here is the actual code I am using:

```
procedure TForm1.btnGetURLClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  moHeader.Lines.Clear;
  moBody.Lines.Clear;
  try
    moBody.text := IdHttp1.Get(edURL.text);
  finally
  end;
end;
```

When the request is complete, the http_result should contain the HTML from the URL specified.  This doesn't seem to work however, so I get the feeling I should perhaps be using the IOHandler property or the OnWork event of the component - however the usage doesn't seem obvious to me, and I couldn't find any working examples with google.  I am sure this is something that has been done before, so any help would be appreciated.

Additional Information:
In the spirit of being more specific, I want to know:
1. Am I doing this right to begin with (or did I miss something?).
2. If so, why might it not be working.
3. It is always possible that there is a bug in the combination of compiler/os/Indy I am using. (Although it should be working).

I should mention, I always get a popup "Connection Closed Gracefully".  This seems to be an exception, and it could be interfering with the result of the function.  I attempted to trap this with a TRY...FINALLY, but it doesn't work.  Probably because Indy is triggering the exception in the background after the Get method runs I suppose.

Finally, here is a screencast of the program running to clear up any confusion:
http://screencast.com/t/NDMzNTQ5
I expect the HTML to fill the second memo box.

Comment: This should work. Maybe you can show the part where you create `IdHTTP1`. I guess that if you're not using a form, you do that manually in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, just like everywhere else in life, when you say that something doesn't work, you need to be more specific. What happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Actually, I am making it on a form now for testing, I mentioned doing it without the GUI component because I plan to use it in a library eventually.  Right now, of course, my focus is on getting it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, would be to use [synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/start).  This is all that is needed to retrieve a webpage using this library:

```
uses
  ...,HTTPSEND;

var
  Result : TStrings;


  if HTTPGetText('http://www.google.com',Result) then
    // do something with result
```

Synapse is a lightweight TCPIP library.  The library is being actively maintained and the current version runs fine in Delphi 2009/2010.  It is NOT a component based framework, so it is very easy to use with other threading techniques ([OmniThreadLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/) or [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=100) for example).

Comment: I will certainly take a look at it.  I went with Indy because I was familiar with it from using it years ago in Delphi 6 or so.

Comment: I got Synapse working with a little work (Supports FPK out of the box, but not on MacOS/BSD...).  This is a good option for my use I think, but I will leave the question open a little longer, since having it answered by fixing Indy may help other people who search for such an answer later.

Answer (score 4):

i think you have the TIdHTTP.**[HandleRedirects](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdHTTP_HandleRedirects.html)** property set to false, if you get the error "[HTTP/1.1 302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)" you can try this

```
var
http_result:string;    
Begin
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects:=True;
http_result := IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.google.com');

End;
```

Comment: Hi, this actually was happening.  I turned the HandleRedirects property to true now.  

I still get the: HTTP/1.1 302 Found, though.

Comment: A 302 is a redirect.  TIdHTTP handles it just fine, as long as the server is providing a "Location" header with a new URL.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the property HandleRedirects to true.

There's no need for a form, using GExperts components to code I got this:

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;

IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
with IdHTTP do
begin
  Name := 'IdHTTP';
  AllowCookies := True;
  HandleRedirects := True;
  HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
end;
```

Just paste this in your unit, it should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Iirc if the website redirects, you also need to override some handler (onredirect or so). But this was also the case in indy9 iirc.

Comment: I plan on using this with a local daemon, so redirects won't be an issue, but it could be that they are at the moment, since I have been testing with www.google.com, etc.  On the other hand, I can't get *any* site to work so far, which lead me to believe I must be doing it the wrong way.

Comment: TIdHTTP handles redirects automatically by default.  Look at the HandleRedirects and RedirectMaximum properties.

Answer (score 0):

This question has lingered open for quite some time, so I am closing it out.  My solution was to just use Synapse, as one of the posters suggested.  It works on windows/Linux/Mac OS with minimal modifications, and works fine in libraries/threads.