# How to get the "Text" of a html page ? (Webbrowser - Delphi)

Tags: html, delphi, text, browser

I'm using WebBrowser to get source of html pages .
Our page source have some text and some html tags . like this :

```
FONT&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P align=center&gt;&lt;FONT color=#ccffcc size=3&gt;**Hello There , This is a text in our html page** &lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;P align=center&gt; &lt;/P&gt;
```

Html tags are random and we can not guess them . So is there any way to get texts only and separating them from html tags ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use a [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) instance to parse and select the plaint text from html code.

see this sample

```
uses
MSHTML,
SHDocVw,
ActiveX;

function GetPlainText(Const Html: string): string;
var
DummyWebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
Document       : IHtmlDocument2;
DummyVar       : Variant;
begin
   Result := '';
   DummyWebBrowser := TWebBrowser.Create(nil);
   try
     //open an blank page to create a IHtmlDocument2 instance
     DummyWebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
     Document := DummyWebBrowser.Document as IHtmlDocument2; 
     if (Assigned(Document)) then //Check the Document
     begin
       DummyVar      := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant); //Create a variant array to write the html code to the  IHtmlDocument2
       DummyVar[0]   := Html; //assign the html code to the variant array
       Document.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(DummyVar).VArray)); //set the html in the document
       Document.Close;
       Result :=(Document.body as IHTMLBodyElement).createTextRange.text;//get the plain text
     end;
   finally
     DummyWebBrowser.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you . but with using this function , result is : "FONT></P><P align=center><FONT color=#ccffcc size=3>**Hello There , This is a text in our html page** </FONT></P><P align=center> </P>"  .  html tags are here still .

Comment: By nested functions was solved : GetPlainText(GetPlainText(MyString)); . :D Thank you Mr Piruz

Comment: @RRUZ With this function I get funny characters (Ã¼, ÃŸ, etc.) from German Umlaut characters (ü, ß, etc.). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This code performs well in most situations. However, caution should be taken as it becomes unresponsive on websites with invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using the [Delphi DOM HTML parser](http://htmlp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you . i need more description (also the question is edited)

Answer (score 1):

If your asterisk is constant, you can simply get everychar between `**`.
If your asterisk is not constant you can rewrite this string and erase all tags (things who starting from `&lt;` and ending with `&gt;`. Or you can use some **DOM parser library** for it.

Answer (score 1):

In essence: in general you can't.

HTML is a markup language with such a wide use and mind boggling possibilities to change the content dynamically that it is virtually impossible to do this (just look at how hard the web browser suppliers need to work to pass for instance the acid tests). So you can only do a subset.

For specific and well defined subsets of HTML, then you have a better chance:

> First you need to get the HTML in a
>   string, then parse that HTML.

Getting the HTML can be done for instance using Indy (see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742900/tidhttp-in-indy-10)).

Parsing highly depends on your HTML and can be quite complex, you can try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733972/best-lightweight-html-parser-for-delphi) or [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+html+parser).

You could use TWebBrowser as RRuz suggests, but it depends on Internet Explorer.
Modern Windows systems do not guarantee that Internet Explorer is installed any more...

--jeroen

Comment: Hi Jeroen , i'm using EmbeddedWebBrowser componenet and there is no prooblem :)

Comment: Until you run your software on a computer that has no Internet Explorer installed; then it will fail. That might not be a problem, but it is something you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Using Delphi HTML Component Library getting text only from HTML document is simple. 
THtDocument.InnerText property returns formatted text without tags.

Comment: The text extraction result is great! Although you'll have to parse something like `THtCanvasGDI` when creating `ThtDocument`...